# How to stop flask from running my server when creating migrations?

Tags: flask, flask-migrate

Whenever I run a command like `flask db migrate` or `flask db upgrade` using the `flask-migrate` framework, it always starts running my application on localhost, and I have to press `CTRL+C` to quit before allowing the server to stop and generate the migration. How can I avoid this?

Another question I have is whenever I run, it will first run it in debug mode and after hitting `CTRL+C` to quit it will again run without debug mode on, on a different port. How do I only limit to running with the former? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere within your application you have a `app.run()` call. Flask runs your application itself, this extra call is the one that is causing the `db` commands to run the server before carrying out the command, and also causes the server to run twice when you do `flask run`. If you find that and remove this line I think you will be fine.